# Ruby On Rails: Mongoid get values of multiple fields as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

My `Detail` model have fields like:

```
email1,email2,email3
```

How do I get all the values, of a particular record, of these fields at once.
Something like:

```
detail = Detail.find(id)
output = detail.only(:email1,:email2,email3)  

=> ["email1","email2","email3"]    #desired output.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the attributes as a hash and call `values_at` with multiple arguments:

```
detail.attributes.values_at('email1', 'email2', 'email3')
#=> [...]
```

One caveat is that the keys are stored as strings, so you'll need to convert your symbols first.

Comment: what if few of them are nil?

Comment: email1,email2,email3 and so on

Comment: The keys or the values?

Comment: the value. okay. find out myself. it's returning empty string.